# Pickle data was truncated — only a problem when sending from macos

Tags: python-3.x, macos, sockets, pickle

I am trying to send data from my local machine, running Big Sur 11.2.3, to a remote server.

**server.py**

```py
import socket, pickle
import env

print("Server is listening on port %s..." % env.PORT)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((env.HOST, env.PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected to %s" % str(addr))

data = []
while True:
    packet = conn.recv(1024)
    if not packet: break
    data.append(packet)
data = pickle.loads(b"".join(data))
print(data)
conn.close()
```

**client.py**

```py
import socket, pickle
import env

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((env.HOST, env.PORT))

variable = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] * (2**14)

data_string = pickle.dumps(variable)
s.send(data_string)

s.close()
print('Data sent to server')
```

This originally worked when using `variable = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, and to simulate sending a larger object I just multiplied it by large number. I originally thought it was failing if the data was larger than the number of bytes I was specifying the server to receive as each packet, but this code works all the way up until I multiply by `2**14` (using `2**13` works).

The weird part is that if I try this from my Raspberry Pi (that is, sending the data from pi to remote server), it works fine. But when I do the same from my macbook, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 17, in <module>
    data = pickle.loads(b"".join(data))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

What could be the reason for this failing to work on macOS?
If I try this locally (that is, running a server and client instance both on my macbook), it works fine, but fails when I try to send from mac to another machine (it also fails when I try to send to from mac to pi).

I read that there is a possibility of issues when the machines sending and receiving the pickled data are running different versions of python, but I don't believe that to be the issue here. The remote server is running python 3.6.9, and my pi is running python 3.7.3. To make sure, I ran the script on my macbook in a virtual env running 3.6.9 and it still failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> s.send(data_string)
> ```

You are lucky that it **only** fails on MacOS. `send` does not guarantee to send all data but you are supposed to check how much actually was send and call `send` again (and possibly again) for sending the rest. Or use `sendall`.

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send):

> Returns the number of bytes sent. **Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent**; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data.

Why does `send` behave differently on different platforms or environments? Because `send` just puts the data into the sockets send buffer. The buffer has a limited size which can be specific to the OS, OS configuration, application, current state of the system (i.e. memory pressure or not) ... . A single `send` will only put as much data into the send buffer as is currently free space in there. If the buffer is full it will block until some space gets free. But it will not make sure that everything can be put into the socket buffer.